# Engine Yard Push/Load Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, engineyard

I am thinking of deploying my Rails app to Engine Yard. I have a MySql db with all of the data for the site. When I deploy to engine yard cloud, will I be able to "push" this database to the server somehow?

Something like this (?):
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/

Or can I somehow put the mysql database in the git repo so it is pushed to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/20996676-Restore-or-load-a-database

Use scp to ssh copy your database to the server.